# React Css Modules Каскад

Tags: css, reactjs

Всем привет. Пытаюсь понять как работаю css модули для вложеных компонентов. Как задать стили для Li компонента внтри Ul компонента. Вот код: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-smoke-59nlc
Я хочу поменять цвет третьего Li на красный, как это сделать через Ul компонент?

Answer (score 0):

Если делать именно так как вы хотите, то можно сделать следующим образом:
Создать функцию в Ul.js которая в зависимости от номера будет присваивать класс с цветом, что то вроде того:

```
let testNum = num => {
  return num === 3 ? 'active' : 'normal';
}

const Ul = props => {
  const lis = props.items.map(item => <Li cl={testNum(item)} />);
  return <div className={style.container}>{lis}</div>;
};
```

После добавте в Li.module.css код для них

```
.normal {
  background: #eee;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

И в самом Li.js присваивайте этот класс

```
const Li = props => {
  return <div className={`${style.li} ${style[props.cl]}`}>Li</div>;
};
```

Я точно не знаю что у вас за приложение, но если третий номер это просто стилизация никак не связанная с логикой, то можно сделать значитеьно проще - добавить изменения только в Li.module.css

```
.li:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}
```

Это немного идёт в разрез с идеалогией реакта, но всё зависит от вашего проекта.
В целом решения грубые, но с этим уже можно работать.

Comment: Как вам такое решение? https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-wildflower-t00cd Просто суть была именно из модуля ul css добавить стилей какому-то из детей.

Comment: Данный код тоже работает, но нарушается немного идеалогия реакта, как бы props должен скорее определять правила компонента, а не передавать их, потому что вы и там и там ипортируете Li.module.css мне кажется это не совсем корректно, к тому же, когда вы не передаёте props, но вызвываете его в компоненте, то у вас в классе появляется undefined, что вообще никак не хорошо. И в присвоении класса "плюс" ставить не нужно